# Is it safe to get bitmask from hash like this (uint64_t)0x1L << (uint64_t)((name_hash) % 63L)

Tags: c++, hash

```
template<typename T>
static constexpr MetatypeHash build_hash() {
        using sanitized = std::remove_const_t<std::remove_reference_t<T>>;
        MetatypeHash hash;
        hash.name_hash = MetatypeHash::hash<sanitized>();
        hash.matcher_hash |= (uint64_t)0x1L << (uint64_t)((hash.name_hash) % 63L);
        return hash;
};
```

Each metatype has name_hash - a 64bit FNV-1a hash of the type name(string)

matcher_hash - is a bit, set in some random position. Think of it as a bit signature of archetype.. 
Archetypes are stored in container, we can query archetypes form container using bitmask.

```
auto build_matcher = [](const std::vector<MetatypeHash>& types) {
    size_t and_hash = 0;

    for (auto type : types)
    {
        and_hash |= type.matcher_hash;
    }
    return and_hash;
};
```

This code form DECS https://github.com/vblanco20-1/decs

**Question:** is this method of generating bit signature form hash is good enough for the purpose? I think we gonna get big collision probability(due to modulo operation) much more then actual collision probability for the hash function used for name_hash. How can i estimate this probability?

Comment: `(uint64_t)0x1L` => `UINT64_C(0x1)`. But just use 0x1ULL which is guaranteed to be at least 64-bit long anyway. And you don't need a cast on the right side. In shift operators the result only depend on the left side (and in other operators both sides are automatically promoted to the common type) => `0x1ULL << (hash.name_hash & 0x3F)`

Comment: Thanks, but question was about collisions. The code shown "as is" from DECS project and syntax is not the subject of discussion...

Comment: A 64-bit number has 2^64 possible values. Your `matcher_hash` only 63 possible values (btw., why don't you use 64?). Of course it has a much-much greater collision probability. But I don't understand your question. What do you mean by "hash is valid"?

Comment: >What do you mean by "hash is valid"?  Think of it as a "Is this method is OK for this purpose?"  
>(btw., why don't you use 64?). The code is not mine, I don't know. It is from https://github.com/vblanco20-1/decs